# Retrieved JSON contains [0.0] randomly in the data

Tags: blackberry

I've been retrieving json from my web service, with the data containing [0.0] in odd places, such as in the middle of "tit[0.0] le". I'm viewing the info in the console, so I just ignored it as when I actually use it it is not present.

However, I'm currently building a calendar and placing the retrieved events in it. The problem with a particular event is that the [0.0] seems to be lodged in between the timestamp 2012-03-[0.0] 01T00:00:00. It's only happening with this event that the [0.0] is not going away when I use it. Of course, the httpdateparser cant retrieve the date properly, with it interpreting it a day early. I think the [0.0] is the cause.

How do I get rid of the [0.0]? parse it out? I don't think it is actually there...

EDIT:

it looks like the [0.0] are just added by the blackberry console for viewing purposes.

But why is it only on the two events that are not working correctly?

```
full_date:2012-02-29T00:00:00
full_date:2012-03-01T00:00:00
```

Both these dates are parsed using the following:

```
Date date = new Date(HttpDateParser.parse(date_full));
                c.setTime(date);
                int theMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); 
                int theYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); 
                int theDate = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

For theDate I get feb 28 and 29 respectively. Does this have to do with leap years? I thought Calendar delt with this stuff?

Comment: Are you able to call your web service using some other client? Are those 0.0s still there? If so, then your web service is a problem and you should give us more details about your web service.

Comment: read edits. It turns out they are just markers on the console. The data is fine. But my other problems other those dates at the end of february being seen a day earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the list of valid date formats on the [API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/http/HttpDateParser.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29). I found `"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssTZD" (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00)` is on it. Maybe you need to append timezone information.

*[EDITED]*

Adjusting the date comes from web service to the device timezone may fix the problem. When `calender.get(property)` is invoked it considers device timezone.